# SQL: Comparing 2 tables and returning any mismatched records

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-workbench, where-clause

I have 2 tables, orders and orderlines, linked with the key orderID. The orders entries are comprised of different sales/unit amounts  and are logged in the orderlines table as separate records. (example seen below)

[image: Multiple orderlines records total to one orders record]

I want to be able to make a query that validates/error checks that the sales/units values in the orders table corresponds with the sum of the orderlines for that certain productID, and returns the orderIDs that have mismatches in sales/units totals.

So far i have the following query but I’m getting the error code 1111 or 1248.

[image: Code sample]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are missing an alias after the subquery in the `from` clause.  I consider this a typographical error, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't aggregate correctly the table orderlines.
You compare the sums without returning them from the query.
Try this:

```
select o.orderid
from orders o inner join (
  select orderid, sum(sales) sumsales, sum(units) sumunits
  from orderlines
  group by orderid 
) s on s.orderid = o.orderid
where s.sumsales <> o.sales or s.sumunits <> o.units
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this worked for me. was my issue just in my syntax with the orderlines inner join?

Comment: Your code tried to use non existing columns like sum(sales) and sum(units) which should be calculated inside the query. Also you tried to join on another non returned column orderlines.orderid.